Flask debug info
after running Flask I saw this output on the console. How do I disable it and what is it? I have no idea how it appeared and I use it. Thx for any ideas
* Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://localhost:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
#define FLAG_LOWER  0x01
...
#define FLAG_XDIGIT 0x10

static unsigned int ctype_table[256] = {
    0, /* 0x0 '\x00' */
    ...
    0, /* 0x21 '!' */
    ...
    FLAG_DIGIT|FLAG_XDIGIT, /* 0x30 '0' */
    ...
    
    0, /* 0x3a ':' */
    0, /* 0x3b ';' */
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
};
...
#define ISLOWER(c) (ctype_table[Py_CHARMASK(c)] & FLAG_LOWER)
...
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 121-492-446

What is this and how to turn this off?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

ide writes on top app.py
from Tools.scripts.make_ctype import method
